# Aggregating features values based on distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, distance-matrix, aggregation

In a polygon dataset, I try to summarize values of surrounding features based on a minimum distance if their area is too small (e.g. 500 square meters).
For example, I have 3 polygons with 300, 250 and 450 square meters that sum up to 1000 square meters. They might not need to touch each other so using `aggregate()` for features that tough each other is not possible.

[image]

*The area of the selected (yellow) features should be aggregated to a total sum. The violet points represent the centroids.*

I already tried via a distance matrix (based on the centroids of the polygons) to find out the distances between the centroids of each polygon feature. My consideration was that I can join the distances between the polygon centroids to the polygons, then filter for small distances (e.g. within 50 meters) to identify polygons that lie within this 50-meter threshold and then aggregate them via an `id` field. However, this resulted in a 1 to n join (or a value relation) because every single centroid has n-1 distances to all other centroids in the dataset.

I can't figure out how to aggregate the values. I also need to integrate the workflow into a graphical model. Any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: The problem is not clear to me. Can you provide more details and a screenshot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'grid_test'* with nine features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Centroids"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#centroids) (This step you already did)

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** By means of the ["DBSCAN clustering"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering) get those groups within a 50-meter threshold

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Use any preferred method to aggregate the values based on newly created `"CLUSTER_ID"` field. I deployed the ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate).

[image: step_3]

and finally get the output

[image: output]

Comment: you are welcome @_@